# Helm: set empty array in chart values via command line

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I previously added an array/list value to the Helm chart values through the command line using

```
--set plugins.install[0]='xxx'
```

I now need to delete this entry, but fail to accomplish it. My goal is to end up with an empty array.
I have already tried with:

```
--set plugins.install[0]=null
--set plugins.install={}
--set plugins.install=null
```

But so far it seems that in all three cases one of the corresponding pods no longer starts. So it seems like this is not the way to go? Any advice is welcome.

I also tried `--set plugins.install=[]`, but then I get an error when upgrading the chart.
`range can't iterate over []`.

To give some more context: this is about the sonarqube chart.

Comment: I've always found the `--set` syntax to be a little finicky.  Can you use a `-f` YAML-format values file instead?  Have you verified in template code what `.Values.plugins.install` is actually set to?

Comment: @DavidMaze I specifically did not want to go through the process of having to maintain a yaml file, but if it is the only option that works, I will just have to :). It's weird that it just does not work with `--set` :). 
The original value is set to be an empty list. https://github.com/SonarSource/helm-chart-sonarqube/blob/master/charts/sonarqube/values.yaml

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Helm documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#the-format-and-limitations-of---set), you should be able to assign an empty array/list in the following manner.

```
--set plugins.install=[]
```

Comment: I was working under the assumption this was the first thing I attempted :| . Let's try...

Comment: This gives me an error ending with `range can't iterate over []`